# Chart.js time axis (automatically calculated range) falls apart when data range is greater than 2073600 seconds (24 days)

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a program that combines data from a text file and plots it to chart using Chart.js. Everthing works fine with regards to generating the data, however when it comes to plotting it, charting seems to fall apart when the range of data is greater than 24 days.

The only work around that I've found is to manually set the 'min' and 'max' ticks for the x-axis but it seems like some unnecessary processing on my end.

new data comes in as files:
[link to codepen](https://codepen.io/Sdamico/pen/VweGmEe)

```
function loadJs(file, id) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = file;
    script.onreadystatechange= function () {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') loadChartData();
    };
    script.onload = loadChartData;
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.id = (typeof id !== 'undefined' ? id : '');
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

[video showing problem](https://gfycat.com/bestscholarlydragon)

Comment: What do you mean by "fall apart"?

Comment: If the data range is 24 days, the x-axis displays a range that is astronomically larger than 24 days.